# FileContentResult null from Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method in my Controller;

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Process(int id)
        {
                var file = ServiceUtilities.FileManager.GetFile(id);

                if (file != null)
                {
                    var fcr = new FileContentResult(new byte[1], @"Image\Gif");
                    return fcr;
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
        }
```

And I am calling this code from my Unit Test as follows;

```
var response =
            new Controllers.FileController().Process(1) as FileStreamResult;


Assert.IsNotNull(response);
```

However, response is always null. If I set a breakpoint on `fcr` in Controller code, it is not null.

For clarification, `file` is a mocked object and is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but `FileContentResult` (what you return from your method) is NOT a `FileStreamResult` (what you cast it to in your test). They both inherit from `FileResult`, but in order for your test to pass, `FileContentResult` would need to inherit from `FileStreamResult`.

Or is that a mis-type?

Comment: Nope, just me being a moron at this late hour!

Comment: LOL! we've all been there @ChrisBint. Doin it as we speak.

Comment: John, hope you get more points and can contribute by commenting too

Comment: Dave, Yes! I can finally comment. Shew. Thanks! :)